# Does Bound by Moonsilver prevent crewing?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does [Bound By Moonsilver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBound%20By%20Moonsilver%5d) prevent a creature enchanted by it from crewing a vehicle? My opponent crewed a vehicle with a [Pyrohound](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPyrohound%5d) I had enchanted with Bound By Moonsilver and we weren't sure if this was actually possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bound by Moonsilver does not prevent crewing. Bound by Moonsilver has the ability

> Enchanted creature can't attack, block, or transform.

Crewing a vehicle is none of those things, so Bound by Moonsilver does not affect it.

Here are the [rules for Crew](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Crew):

> - **702.121a** Crew is an activated ability of Vehicle cards. “Crew N” means “Tap any number of untapped creatures you control with total power N or greater: This permanent becomes an artifact creature until end of turn.”
> - **702.121b** **A creature “crews a Vehicle” when it’s tapped to pay the cost to activate a Vehicle’s crew ability.**
> - **702.121c** If an effect states that a creature “can’t crew Vehicles,” that creature can’t be tapped to pay the crew cost of a Vehicle.

So, the only way to stop a creature from crewing a vehicle is either with an effect that specifically says so, like [Revoke Privileges](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRevoke%20Privileges%5d) as doppelgreener mentioned, or by keeping it tapped with an effect like on [Malfunction](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMalfunction%5d).

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't. Bound by Moonsilver says:

> Enchanted creature can't attack, block, or transform.

... so that's all the creature is prevented from doing, and Crewing is none of those things.

Currently the only card that specifically prevents a creature from crewing is [Revoke Privileges](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRevoke%20Privileges%5d), which says:

> Enchanted creature can't attack, block, or **crew Vehicles**.